# 2019 2-letters 33-length list

Tags: letters, letter-sequence

Find the final 2-letters element of the following list:

> AQ AR AT BA BA BA BO CA CY EQ FE FO GO GY HA HO JU KA MO RO RU SA SH
>      SK SP SU TA TA TE TR VO WE ??

---

## Classification

The 33 elements can be classified into $3$ categories:

- XY $>1$ `Category 1:` 
  BA2 BA3 FO HA RU VO
- XY $\tilde \ge ~1$ `Category 2:` AQ AR AT BA1 BA CA CY EQ FE GY JU RO SA SH TA TE TR
- XY $=1$ `Category 3:` BO GO KA MO SK SP SU TA WE ??

$\tilde \ge 1$ 
   means it is partially equal to $1$ and partially greater than $1$.

---

### Hint

Ak19's comment

> In response to Ak19's comment, these are not state nor country codes

### Note

> This list will probably have to be updated in 5 years from now (2019).

Comment: BA BA BA? Are you sure?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Yes! 100% sure ;)

Comment: The codes sound like country or state codes...

Comment: I have added a classification to make this puzzle easier.

Comment: @Ak19 I've added an hint for your sentence :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are

> Olympic sports

XY >1 are

> Team sports, with number of players on team > 1, such as BAseball, BAsketball, FOotball (soccer), HAndball, RUgby, VOlleyball

XY ≥̃  1 are

> Sports where there are multiple events, some of which are individual and some of which are team, such as AQuatics, ARchery, AThletics, BAdminton, CAnoeing, CYcling, EQuestrian, FEncing, GYmnastics, JUdo, ROwing, SAiling, SHooting, TAekwondo, TEnnis, TRiathlon

XY =1 are

> Purely individual sports, such as BOwling, GOlf, KArate, ...

The missing one is

> WRestling

This will change in 5 years because

> The 2024 Olympics has provisionally added BReakdancing, CLimbing, SKateboarding, and SUrfing.